# What to do with an ISO once you've mounted it (gparted)

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, iso

I've downloaded the gparted "application" from a website using my windows machine, i've put the .iso image onto a usb and transfered it onto my linux machine. I've then followed some instructions and mounted it onto my machine. At this point i was expecting some sort of application to be there where i could double click it and simply run it.

My question is, once i've mounted the gparted iso onto my machine, how do i "run" it. I'm a windows user so i was expecting a .exe file. Is there a step i've missed out?

Additional points: 
I'm downloading this because i need to reduce the size of my main partition.

Link where i got the gparted iso from: http://gparted.org/download.php

Instructions i followed to mount the iso:

*sudo mkdir /media/iso "/n"
sudo mount -o loop myIsoFile.iso /media/iso*

I'm using ubuntu with kernel 4.8

If i've missed anything out please let me know

Comment: The `gparted` is to be used as `boot device` since its on the `usb` make sure its installed there as a `bootable iso` then change the boot order from your bios (assuming the boot order doesn't have `usb` in first place). Now plugin the `usb` and boot into it. The gparted will boot up and present options to modify your disk... __NOTE please backup first, don't say you weren't warned__

Answer (score 0):

The ISO is meant to be burned to a CD, but you could also use `dd` to write it to the flash stick. If you need more info on how to do this, then just drop a comment below :)

**Also, keep in mind that you can't resize your main partition while you're booted from it.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I don't actually have any CDs and my linux computer isn't connected to the computer hence the use of the USB to transfer it onto my linux machine from my windows machine. I can't use the dd command in windows (or i don't think i can)

Comment: @bahjat Correct, Windows doesn't have `dd`. You will have to copy the ISO to your Linux machine, and then `dd` it back to the flash stick. I suggest adding the `BS=4M` argument, which will make it go much faster.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand, the dd command just copies the iso image. I can do that by copying the .iso image using my GUI. Also why do i need to copy the .iso back into my USB? I'm really new to linux

Comment: @bahjat - Okay, first things first: you will not be able to resize your partition if you run Gparted from your normal Linux install, because as I said earlier, EXT4 partitions can't be resized while they are mounted. Thus, you have to boot the Gparted live ISO file. The reason that you have to use `dd` is because **simply copying the ISO to the flash drive with the GUI will not write the MBR sector, and thus the USB drive won't be bootable.** Also, just FYI, when you `dd` the ISO back to the flash drive, any other data on there will be erased.